# Unable to iterate strings in a problem related to recursion

Tags: c++

The problem is to remove "x" from a string place it behind the string

for example

Input:
"axxbxcx"

Output:
"abcxxxx"

Why is it giving an error that is "ISO C++ forbids comparison between
pointer and integer" I don't get it and how should I fix it

Code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string removex(string s, int i = 0, int c = 0)
{
    if(s.length() == i)
    {
        return "";

        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            cout << "x";
        }
    }

    if(s[i] == "x")
    {
        cout << "";
        c++;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << s[i];
    }

    removex(s, i + 1, c);
}

int main()
{
    string s = "axxbxxcc";

    removex(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(s[i] == "x")` should be `if(s[i] == 'x')`

Comment: Not all execution paths in the function return a value. Furthermore the `for` loop should be removed, since it's never executed. Btw: Using `std::partition` the (non-recursive) implementation is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

A single character, `'x'`, is not the same as a single-character string, `"x"`.

The mysterious error message is caused by `s[i]`, which is a `char`, being promoted to `int`, while `"x"`, which is a `const char[2]`, decays into a pointer to its first element.
So `s[i] == "x"` is a comparison between `int` and `const char*`

You also return *before* the "print x" loop, which will skip the loop.
On top of that, you are not returning anything from all paths, so if you fix the compilation error you have some undefined behaviour to look forward to.

But you are complicating this by counting the xes.

A simpler recursive definition:

- If you have reached the end of the string, do nothing and you're done.
- If you haven't, assume that processing "the rest of the string" will do the right thing, and

  - if the first character is not `'x'`, print the character and then process the rest of the string.
  - if the first character *is* `'x'`, first process the rest of the string, then print `'x'`.

This will print everything that is not `'x'` before everything that is `'x'`.
(You might want to take a minute to convince yourself about this.)

```
void removex(const std::string& s, int i)
{
    if (i >= s.length()) {
        return;
    }
    if (s[i] != 'x') {
        cout << s[i];
    }
    removex(s, i+1);
    if (s[i] == 'x') {
        cout << 'x';
    }    
}
```